# Angular 2: Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response

Tags: mongodb, angular, express, mongoose

I need to delete a record on my mongodb using mongoose.

Here is my component

```
 deleteProduct(product){
        this._confirmationService.confirm({
            message: 'Are you sure you want to delete the item?',
            accept: () => {
                this._productsAdminService.deleteProduct(product._id)
                    .subscribe(products => {
                        products.forEach(function(product){
                            if(product.cat_id === 1) product.catName = 'Dota Shirts';
                            if(product.cat_id === 2) product.catName = 'Gym Shirts';
                            if(product.cat_id === 3) product.catName = 'Car Shirts';
                        });
                        this.products = products;
                    },
                    err => console.log(err));
            }
        })
    }
```

basically this will just pass the product id to the service to execute http request.

Here is my service

```
deleteProduct(productId){
    let headers = new Headers({'Authorization': 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('currentUserToken')});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
    return this._http.delete('http://localhost:3000/admin/products/delete/' + productId, options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this._handlerError);
}
```

I am using the delete method to call my API in expressJS.

Here is my API

```
productsAdminRouter.route('/delete/:productId')
    .delete(function(req,res){
        id = req.params.productId;
        console.log(id);
        Products.findByIdAndRemove(id)
            .exec(function(err, done){
                if (err) throw err;
                Products.find()
                    .exec(function(err, products){
                        res.json(products);
                    });
            });
    });
```

But I always got this error

[image]

Can anyone help? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly like @flashjpr said

I had to write an especific middleware to my entity "ticket".

```
var allowDelete = function(req, res, next){
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE')
  next()
}
```

and pass it to the first middleware of that entity

```
app.use('/tickets', allowDelete, tickets);
```

**EDIT:** I'm using [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem the other day when working with a Java-Spring backend: when Cross-origin resource sharing (or simply `cors`) is happening, Angular sends a`pre-flight` request **before** the actual (*here DELETE*) request which is of type `OPTIONS`(http).

What you have to do is:

- enable CORS on your server
- make sure your server accepts OPTIONS request on that particular endpoint ( `/delete/:productId`)
- add the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header to the response of the OPTIONS, DELETE

Comment: can you teach me how and where to put the access-control-allow-method header on my code? I have authorization header right now and I don't know how to put the access-controll. BTW I have already enabled cors

Comment: Try 
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");  
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PATCH, POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) { 
  return res.send(200);
}